# Do we really need AWS gateway while using Istio service mesh

Tags: amazon-web-services, ddos, amazon-elb, amazon-waf, istio-gateway

I am trying to put a deployment structure on AWS.
I have got bunch of Microservices and I plan to use EKS with Istio service mesh.

What I would like to know is, if I really need to use any AWS periphery services like AWS API gateway, AWS ALB, DNS, etc. The rational behind this question is that Istio already has the potent alternatives in the form of ingress and egress gateways (along with istiod), which pretty much can do everything on traffic routing and service registry, etc.

The only confusion is regarding security services like WAF (for DDOS attacks). I need these security services and hence some component in AWS must be front-ending the user requests to forward them to AWS security services and then to the Istio Gateway.

Appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: AFAIK: ingress is separate from service mesh, and often it needs to use the cloud load-balancer service (alb/elb/nlb), although it is possible to configure some ingress controllers without this. WAF can be configured directly on the LB (also afaik), though this is more complicated as it needs you to statically provision the lb rather than have the ingress controller dynamically provision it. BTW: Hashicorp Consul is a better service-mesh IMO, especially when coupled with Vault.